# Delete autosaved Personal Workbook in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

While working on a VBA project, Excel crashed on my device and all macros got autosaved. But, now I am left with an extra autosaved PERSONAL Workbook and I do not know how to delete it. It's not exactly creating a problem but I assume, it is taking up unnecessary space. It looks like this

[image]

I'd like to delete the whole Autosaved.xlsb project but I do not know how to access its location and there is no option for deletion when I right click on it.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the folder `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` - where XXXX has to be replaced by your windows user name - there you should find the file